# Execute Javascript after directive template has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created my custom directive for rating in angularJS. I want to run javascript after loading of html template. So how can i do that?

my code:

```
 app.directive('ratingControl',function(){
     return {
         restrict:'EA',
         templateUrl:'rating.htm',
         link :function(scope,element,attr) {}
     };
 });
```

Comment: use post function in link...

Comment: @user1760979 how to use post function. Please explain in detail

Comment: You can simply put your JavaScript into link method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$timeout` function in link:

```
// You might need this timeout to be sure it runs after DOM render.
$timeout(function () {
    //your code
}, 0,false);
```

Comment: Yes, where I suppose to put?