# Call function after load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I need to call function after load html template in directive..

```
app.directive('myDivModal',function () {   
    var controller = ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        //some code here..
    }];
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            myprops: '=props'
        },
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        link:function (scope, elem, attr,controller,transcludeFn) { 
            $('#firstId').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
            });
        }
    }     
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="{{myprops.id}}" readonly="readonly" ng-model="start" >
<input type="text" id="{{myprops.id}}" readonly="readonly" ng-model="end" >
```

I need `#firstId` that to bind to `id="{{myprops.id}}Dp1"` .. but the function is started before HTML I try almost everything like post, compile post and so on, but nothing work so help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $timeout function in link:

```
// You might need this timeout to be sure it runs after DOM render.
$timeout(function () {
    //your code
    $('#firstId').datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
}, 0,false);
```

And this is possibly a duplicate question of [Execute Javascript after directive template has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945359/execute-javascript-after-directive-template-has-been-loaded#answer-26945615)

Comment: since he is in link function the $timeout is unecessary as the DOM is already created. i believe the selector doesn't return any elements

Comment: It should because $timeout() puts work on the native event queue, and hence it will be serviced after the browser renders

Answer (score 0):

I think @DB.Null is correct try adding a class property to your html elements and then apply:

```
$('.startDate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller:

```
var controller = ['$scope',function ($scope) {

  ...
  $scope.$on('my-tpl-ready', function() {

    $('#firstId').datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });       

  });

}];
```

Also add this to your template:

```
<div ... ng-init="$emit('my-tpl-ready')">
  ...
</div>
```